# how to retrieve multiple table data with multiple criteria in laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to retrieve data from 4 different table using laravel eloquent with multiple criteria.

### an Overview of my table;

table 1

- id
- name

---

table 2

- id
- name
- year
- table1_id

---

table 3

- id
- name
- description
- table2_id

---

table 4

- id
- name
- quarter
- table3_id

below are their relations

---

table 1

```
hasMany -> table 2
```

table 2

```
 belongsTo ->table1
 HasMany->table2
```

table 3

```
 belongsTo ->table2
 HasMany->table3
```

table 4

```
belongsTo ->table3
```

I'd like to fetch the data by resource show with two parameters
and i tried this

```
   $Report = Table1::whereHas('tabke1', function($query){
        $query->where('year', 'like','%'.$year.'%');
      })
      ->with('table2')->whereHas('table3', function($query){
        $query->where('quarter', 'like', '%'.$quarters.'%');
      })
      ->get();
```

but im receiving syntax error.

How can I retrieve the data from multiple table with multiple filter?
i tried this table query to understand more what i expect

```
SELECT `table1`.*, `table2`.*, `table3`.*, `table4`.*
FROM `table1`, `table2`, `table3`, `table4`
WHERE ((`table2`.* year = 2019) AND (`table4`.* quarter = 1))
```

Comment: What's the syntax error?

Comment: Call to undefined method App\tabl1::table4()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon there are two queries to achieve the results.

The first query is something like:

```
Table1::whereHas('table2', function ($query) {
    $query->where('year', 2019);
})
->whereHas('table2.table3.table4', function ($query) {
    $query->where('quarter', 1);
})
->get();
```

The second query is something like:

```
Table1::select('table1.*')
->join('table2', 'table1.id', '=', 'table2.table1_id')
->join('table3', 'table2.id', '=', 'table3.table2_id')
->join('table4', 'table3.id', '=', 'table4.table3_id')
->where('table2.year', 2019)
->where('table4.quarter', 1)
->distinct()
->get();
```

Regarding performance, I prefer the second query.